# Unable to pass data to a PUT request

Tags: node.js, superagent

I am trying to use Superagent to send an update to a mongoDB record.
I pass the _id of the object in the URL but I am unable to pass the new data to Super agent it seems.

```
 put: (url,body,callback) => {  // Api.put('/api/polls/' + pollId,data
        console.log('put ' + url); // path is here
        console.log('obj ' + body); // data is here
        superagent
            .put(url)
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .send(body)
            .end((err, response) => {
                if (err) { 
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(err, null);
                    return;}
                // here check for API failures
                const confirmation = response.body.confirmation;
                if (confirmation != 'success') {
                    // send a failure message
                    callback({message:response.body.message, null});
                    return;
                }
                callback(response, response.body);
            })


    },
```

> ```
>       See problem in Superagent.put call...nothing in data

[image: super agent call screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by an incorrect update request to mongoose.
The data = "unidentified" had nothing to do with it.